# My version of RubyGems is too new to install RubyInline/ZenTest

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zentest

I'm trying to install the RubyInline gem, but to no avail. It says that ZenTest needs RubyGems between versions 1.8 and 2.1. I have RubyGems 2.1.7.

Is RubyInline/ZenTest working on making it compatible with the newer versions?

Comment: It seems the post omitted the first word of my header, which originally was "Hello, World:". I'm not trying to sound rude.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known (and reported issue) that the author has commented on here:

https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/issues/48

Feel free to 'watch' that thread for a posted release that fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ZenTest are you running? The current is 4.9.3.

Try running `gem out ZenTest` or `gem list ZenTest` to see if yours is out of date.

You can update all your stale gems using `gem up`.

You can clean out the stale gems after that using `gem clean`.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man for your quick reply. I don't have ZenTest at all.

Comment: The current revision of Rubygems is 2.1.2, so I'm not sure where 2.1.7 comes from. And what happens when you try `gem install ZenTest -v4.9.3`?

Comment: You're right, it's 2.1.2...I was looking at the wrong number. I still get the same error message "ZenTest requires RubyGems version < 2.1, >= 1.8. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself".